xskak's pastfen and nextfen do not appear to work
I like to display the board before the last move was made. This makes it easier for myself to go through all the alternative moves and their variations if I do not constantly have to substract the last move from the position show in the diagram.
However, pastfen and nextfen do not work as I expect them to work.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1.e4 c5}

The past: \xskakget{pastfen} (I expect it to show the FEN after 1.e4 but before 1...c5).

The future: \xskakget{nextfen} (I expect it to show the FEN after 1...c5).

\mainline{2.Nf3 Nc6}

The following command does display the expected FEN.

\chessboard

The past: \xskakget{pastfen}

The future: \xskakget{nextfen}

\chessboard[setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]

\end{document}

I use Overleaf and the logs show
Package: xskak 2019/06/23 version v1.5 extended chess typesetting and parsing

which I believe is the latest version of the package.
What am I missing? What do I do wrong?

the moveid is not automatically changed by \mainline, so you are retrieving info for the first move. You need to set to the last move first, with \xskakset{lastmoveid}.
